# HTML & CSS - Issue with margins in IE and Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, compatibility

I've been stumped at this for the past 2 hours and I am looking for some help. Basically this layout works fine in Firefox (The text spacing, the elements and contact form all look good). In IE & Chrome the top margin of everything seems almost double. Here is the code:

HTML

```
<div id="contentBody">
<br>Company</br>
<p>Address 1</p>
<p>Address 2</p>
<br>Tel</br>
<br>Fax</br>
<br>E-Mail</br>
<div id="ekontakt">
<p>
<p><b>Title</b></p> <p>Name</p>  <p>E-Mail</p>
<p><b>Title</b></p> <p>Name</p>  <p>E-Mail</p>
<p><b>Title</b></p> <p>E-Mail</p>
</div>

<div id="map-canvas">
    <a href="google maps link" target="blank" />            
    <img src="images/map.jpg" />
    </a>
</div>

<form action="mailer.php" method="post" class="contactform">
 <!-- Bunch of Labels removed, these work fine -->  
</form>

</div>
```

CSS

```
#ekontakt
{   
    font-size:12px;
    margin:2em auto -32em 0em;
}

#map-canvas {
    background-image: url(../images/map.jpg);
        width: 300px;
        height: 200px;
    margin:33.5em 0em -50em 0em;
    line-height: 0px;
}

.contactform {
    margin: -5em -7em 0em 30em;
    max-width: 500px;
    background: #555;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    font: 12px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #D3D3D3;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #444;
    border: 2px solid;
    border-radius: 0px;
    border-color: #FFFFFF;
    opacity: 0.8;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: A lot of this HTML is invalid; there is no closing tag for a `<br>` (In HTML5, the tag is simply `<br>`, in XHTML it's `<br />`), the `<p>` tag isn't closed on line 9 and you have a self-closing `a` on line 16.  Maybe if those errors were fixed, the layout would be fixed?

Comment: In #contentBody you have opening and closing BR tags. BR tags don't work like that. It's just one tag <br> placed after the element you want to be on it's own line. Also in #ekontakt you have an opening P tag that doesn't close. Try fixing these problems and see if it works as expected.

Comment: As @ScottKaye has said, invalid code. Make http://validator.w3.org/ your friend.

Comment: The "layout" of the HTML (where the tags are actually positioned on the line) look more like the OP is trying to create a table - is this the case, @AaronK?

Comment: true... i guess i am having sleep deprivation that is some sloppy coding.

reinspected the br and p tags and the formatting is normal now on chrome, and almost right on IE, although the top spacing still isnt 100% right